# Eclipse debugger cannot find source when breakpoint is in parent class

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

When my breakpoint is set in an ancestor class, the Eclipse debugger stops at the correct breakpoint, but displays the "Source not found" error. The title of the window, instead of showing the class name like normal, has the full ConcreteClass(ParentClass) name, including the parentheses. This is the same string that shows in the debug window containing the executing stack.

So, no wonder it can't find that class. But why is it doing that?

For instance, in the source tab, the title it says it is looking for says:
TransferOfFundsAction(DocumentActionBase)

where DocumentActionBase is the class with the breakpoint, and TransferOfFundsAction is the child class being executed.

Comment: Is the parent class within the same project? Or is it in some other project that is referenced by the project containing the class being debugged?

Comment: This is happening both with parent classes in the same project, and classes from a jar file (included in the project classpath).

Comment: If the parent class is in a project you can attach its source while debugging by right-clicking the method stack in the Debug view and selecting Edit Source Lookup.

Comment: Yes, I know how to attach source. Re-read my question. The class it is looking for appears to be the include the concrete class, plus the parent class in parentheses. It will never find a class with that name, as it is not a valid java class name.

Comment: Try ctrl+shift+t and search the class your debugging. If your not able to see the source you will need to attach it. Regarding the parent class name in parenthesis, that's normal if your looking at the debug view.

Comment: Ctrl+shift+T seems to be about the same as Ctrl+Shift+R. Yes, the class exists, in fact I can have it already open when the debugger opens the new tab with the error message.

I know that format is normal for the debug view. I was using that example so you would know what I was talking about. But I don't think that is correct for the source tab title, is it? 

Again, the source tab title contains the full name: ConcreteClass(AncestorClass) including both names and the parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Eclipse 4.4.1 and I could fix it by defining the "Project" in the Debug Configuration and set it to the current project where the source or library references are defined which are needed.